# How do I access a function from a controller in zend 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Finally, I succeeded installing zf2 , now I'm trying to accessing a function but i get the 404 page .

This is my code :
namespace Application\Controller;

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController{

    public function indexAction(){
        return new ViewModel();
    }
    public function addAction(){
        echo 1;
    }

    public function editAction(){
    }

    public function deleteAction(){
    }
}
```

when i access mylink/**add** it redirects me to 404. Why ?

This is the route:

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
            // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
            // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
            // using the path /application/:controller/:action
            'application' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/application',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'abstract_factories' => array(
            'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
            'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
        ),
        'aliases' => array(
            'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
        ),
    ),
    'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_US',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController'
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
    // Placeholder for console routes
    'console' => array(
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Can someone explain me where i have to modify the route to access the function addAction??? or to access a new controller ? for example : myproject/mynewcontroller or myproject/add ? thx

Comment: I don;t understand for every function and controller i need to create a new route ?

Comment: Yes for every function and controller you need to create a new route, that's how zend MVC works.

Comment: I just updated my post, please check it again , thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a route to call that function, something along the lines of:

```
'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
        'index' => array(
            'type' => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/add',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller' => 'Index',
                    'action' => 'add',
                ),
            ),
```

I'm not entirely sure if this code is valid, since I haven't used routing in zend in a while, but it should be something in that direction. Refer to the zend framework docs for more ino: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html

Comment: I still getting the 404, im accessing my url like this: myproject.com/index/add

Comment: I think this would result in my project.com/add, but you need to have your webserver rewrite rules setup correctly. Otherwise myproject.com/index.php/add may work

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible you forget to add controller `invokables` in your `module.config.php` file **try this:**

```
<?php

return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
        ),
    ),
    ...
    ...
);
```